# Оптимальный способ создания проекта используя PHPStorm

Tags: php, linux, phpstorm, apache2, развертывание

Есть машина с linux ubuntu. Установлен LAMP c PHPStorm. Создать как таковой проект нету. Но как правильно его деплоить на тот же комп что бы работал как локальный сайт. Нашел такой способ:

1)Создайте новую папку для нашего виртуального хоста:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/test.site
```

2)Дадим права на доступ:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

3)Необходимо создать небольшой файл, index.html, чтобы он открылся, когда вы запустите этот сайт:

```
sudo vi /var/www/test.site/public_html/index.html
```

4)Заполнить файл

5)Теперь можно добавлять виртуальный хост, для этого создайте файл и наполните его содержимым:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.site.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.site
    ServerAlias www.test.site
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

6)Теперь сохраните файл, далее нужно активировать наш хост:

```
 sudo a2ensite test.site.conf
```

7)Перезапускаем веб-сервер:

```
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

8)Теперь необходимо завернуть трафик с этого домена на локальный сервер, для этого добавьте строчку в /etc/hosts:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

9)Добавить

```
127.0.0.1 test.site
```

Этот метод работает, но кажется немного неудобным. Можно ли как то это всё сделать внутри PHPStorm.

Comment: я одного не понял - при чем здесь phpstorm

Comment: Ну я думал что PHPStorm позиционирует себя как IDE  а не редактором. Я думал есть более удобный способ сделать это используя PHPStorm.

Comment: и поэтому он должен уметь создавать виртуальные хосты на вашем сервере что ли? покуда пхп шторм не имеет встроенного вэб-сервера, то и заниматься ему подобным нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Создавать виртуальные хосты для локальной разработки смысла нет.
В PHP есть встроенный веб-сервер. Который запускается с помощью команды
`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`
В шторме можно создать конфигурацию, которая будет запускать сервер с помощью этой команды и далее просто жмешь **F5** и у тебя все работает.
А при выгрузке на продакш, на реальном сервере уже и нужно париться с виртуал хостами.
Заодно и код будет так сказать **Low Coupling** с апачем.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь использую это.